# Using CASE WHEN with newly created columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, case

I have a table in SQL Server, I've grouped it by ID and created 2 new columns with the counts of other data. I want to be able to create another column at the same time, which displays a 1 if the counts in both columns are greater than a number, otherwise will display 2. However when I try it, it says invalid column name, I guess as my count columns aren't in the original table?

My data is similar to:

```
    ID    Data1    Data2
-------------------------
0    1       1       5
1    1       2       5
2    1       5       8
3    1       7       9
4    2       8       5
5    2       7       3
6    2       9       2
7    3       3       1
8    3       3       6
9    3       2       7
10   3       6       3
11   3       8       0
```

Desired output (where code is 1 if >= 4, else 2):

```
   ID  CountData1  CountData2  Code
------------------------------------
0   1           4           4     1
1   2           3           3     2
2   3           5           5     1
```

Current query:

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    COUNT(Data1) AS CountData1,
    COUNT(Data2) AS CountData2,
    (CASE WHEN (CountData1 >= 4 and CountData2 >= 4) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS Code
FROM 
    Table
GROUP BY 
    ID
```

Comment: You can't use those in the same select list. Either repeat the count()'s, or use a derived table (subquery).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that SQL statements are parsed, you cannot reference an expression you just created at the same scope.

You can either repeat the expressions again:

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    COUNT(Data1) AS CountData1,
    COUNT(Data2) AS CountData2,
    (CASE WHEN (COUNT(Data1) >= 4 and COUNT(Data2) >= 4) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) 
    AS Code
FROM 
    dbo.Table
GROUP BY 
    ID;
```

Or use a CTE or derived table:

```
-- CTE

;WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT ID, 
      COUNT(Data1) AS CountData1,
      COUNT(Data2) AS CountData2
    FROM dbo.Table 
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT ID, CountData1, CountData2,
  CASE WHEN CountData1 >= 4 AND CountData2 >- 4 
    THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS Code
FROM cte;

-- Derived Table

SELECT ID, CountData1, CountData2,
  CASE WHEN CountData1 >= 4 AND CountData2 >- 4 
    THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS Code
FROM     
(
  SELECT ID, 
      COUNT(Data1) AS CountData1,
      COUNT(Data2) AS CountData2
    FROM dbo.Table 
    GROUP BY ID
) AS DerivedTable;
```

These all perform the same, in spite of some folks who believe the first one is worse because you reference `COUNT()` additional times. SQL Server is pretty good about not repeating work it doesn't have to, and in fact all three queries above yield the exact same execution plan, with the exact same cost, same number of reads, the same output, and the exact same number of expressions are calculated. CPU and duration will vary slightly because, well, computers.

> [image: all three plans are the same]

If you have a case where the CTE yields a *better* plan than repeating the expressions (noting that there are possibly some cases where *both* variations will yield multiple count expressions), please post it somewhere.

Comment: 2nd option is way better than 1st in regards of performance

Comment: @Yaseen Can you demonstrate with some evidence? SQL Server is usually pretty smart about not repeating work (and in fact, when it's not, the CTE approach won't save it).

Comment: More times the Count() functions executes. The performance decreases.
In your first approach Count() was executing four times. While in second approach it just executing 2 times.

Comment: @Yaseen Just because you mention the COUNT() function multiple times doesn't mean it will _execute_ multiple times, and when you use a CTE it doesn't magically mean it _won't_ execute multiple times. Did you try it? I get the exact same execution plan for all three queries, with similar timings/CPU and identical I/O. Again, please show some evidence that the queries will perform differently rather than just assume they will because you counted expressions.

Comment: @Yaseen updated answer. If you have contradictory evidence that demonstrates SQL Server getting the CTE right but failing on the repeated expressions, please post it so we can see.

Comment: I didn't have any evidense as of now, but I did face these issue in one of the project, where we had multiple joins with around 4k data in main table.

Comment: @Yaseen It is simply not true. You can verify from the execution plan that the same expression is only executed once

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TT.ID,TT.CountData1,TT.CountData2,
CASE WHEN TT.CountData1>= 4 and TT.CountData2>=4 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END CODE
FROM
(SELECT ID,
COUNT(Data1) AS CountData1,
COUNT(Data2) AS CountData2
FROM 
   Table
GROUP BY 
 ID)TT;
```